# Suggestion for microservices security spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, netflix-zuul

I want to create a project with **spring boot**, based on **microservices**. I implemented a gateway with **Zuul** and now not sure what to use for the security between microservices. I need the microservices to be aware of the user's permissions when they get a request, also they might communicate with each other, not only gateway.
I am using **spring boot 2.5.7** , but seems that **oauth2** is deprecated, I also read about **spring authorization server**, but it is is experimental.
What should i use for security and also if you have some tutorials will be great.

P.S.
It will help a free solution, even if it means more implementation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some precisions:

Spring Security OAuth2 is deprecated because the OAuth2 features (except the authorization server) were merged into spring security core.
About spring authorization server, the project is no more experimental see releases notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server you can use it as an oauth2 provider.

That means, you can use spring security core to protect your microservices using any OAuth2 provider (Google, Github, Keycloak, etc...). The choice is yours, your requirements are so common nowadays, it will not be really difficult to find a solution.

Comment: But i read that spring authorization server will reach end of life in may 2022, so will it be a good solution for long therm ?

Comment: Where did you read that? If you want a mature solution you can use Keycloak.

Comment: In here https://spring.io/blog/2021/11/08/update-on-eol-for-spring-security-oauth   But now i see i understood it wrong. means that after may 2022 we should migrate to spring authorization server. But i am looking into keycloak . Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do your security only at gateway layer ? and keep your micro-services without security ? Not sure if will fit your requirements.

Check this example using AWS gateway + cognito, same idea:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-stacs-uses-cognito-and-api-gateway/

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it is an interesting point of view and will look into that.